# Compute$\Delta x \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{5}(k\cdot \Delta x)^2+1\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

So, here's what I got:$$\Delta x \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{5}(k\cdot \Delta x)^2+1\right)=\frac{1}{5}(\Delta x)^3\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(k^2+1\right)=\frac{1}{5}(\Delta x)^3\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k^2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}{1}\right)=\frac{1}{5}(\Delta x)^3\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} +n\right)=\frac{1}{5}(\Delta x)^3\left(\frac{1}{3}n^3+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{7}{6}n\right)$$ is there a wrong step, if so which one?

Comment: Yeah, it is, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first equality is basically $$ab + 1 = a\cdot (b+1)$$ which is incorrect unless $a=1$.

In your case, $a = \frac{1}{5}(\Delta{x})^2$ and $b = k^2,$ so your computation is only valid for $|\Delta{x}| = \sqrt{5}.$

---

To fix this, you should instead write a first step as
$$\Delta{x} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{5}(k\cdot\Delta x)^2+1\right) = \Delta{x} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{5}(k\cdot\Delta x)^2\right) + \Delta{x} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n \left(1\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$\Delta x \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n}{(\Delta x)^2}\neq (\Delta x)^3$. It's simply $n\cdot (\Delta x)^3$.